# vue js and jquery DOM manipulation

Tags: jquery, vue.js, dom, semantic-ui, fomantic-ui

I wonder if anybody can give me advice how to approach the situation when I need to access DOM elements directly while I am also using VUE.JS.

I use Fomantic-UI framework (fork of dead Semantic UI). A creation an element takes some time 100ms(?) so the DOM element is not immediately accessible. And I need to call Fomantic method on it. Currently I use setTimeout for 100-200ms but I think this is not a right approach.

(This is not a problem of "mounted"!!! it is a "problem" of reactive response)

e.g. I load a new data. Based on the loaded data VUE creates a new DIV (Fomantic accordion) and then I need to activate it by calling a method on this DIV. If I do it straight away the DIV is still not there.

Any ideas how to approach it properly?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to discuss this abstractly. If there's code, please, provide it, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown what causes 100ms delay in your case. In case there's race condition, address it specifically, like chaining a promise and optionally adding nextTick to wait for data to be rendered in a component

Comment: I got an answer bellow but I think there is no need for a code. The delay is probably shorter but there is delay. Computer are not working in light speed. I mentioned vue js framework. I update variable and this trigger asynchronous action when vuejs pickup the variable change and start building and adding elements to the DOM. This takes always sometime probably very short but not short enough when in the moment of changing the variable I am trying to reach the DOM element already. This is not 100% right approach in reactive framework but I will not rebuild whole Fomantic to be "vue complient"

Comment: "Computer are not working in light speed" - this is specific to asynchronous processes that can be measured and controlled, not to real time. Otherwise you have to resort to quick fix like 100ms random timeout, virtually never has to be like that with first-party code. You need a way to reproduce if you need your problem to be solved, it's very specific to your case and requires to check what's going on

Comment: yes I understand! It is very difficult to troubleshoot anything if you can't see I agree.  If you are using someone else libraries (like vuejs ) you have limited option. If it is my code a set a callback.. but there is nothing what I can do except what was proposed as solution. I understand that I am combining two "incompatible" frameworks and I am looking for the less harmful approach :-D. Thank you anyway to spending your time to help me! I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use MutationObserver and watch when a DOM element indicating the end of DOM creation for your accordeon.
2. Use a first interaction of a user with your accordion and do all your bindings in that event handler.

Comment: thanks I will explore both options but it looks as a good idea. I especially like the user based approach!

Comment: just tested the approach with first user interaction.. :-D  it works of course.. I just wonder why I did not find it by myself.. maybe I am not so smart as I think ;-)

Comment: @Martin i guess that's matter of time invested into a topic